Editing, or copying and changing the column type, of a read-only auto-number column in a Sharepoint list
I had a table in MS Access, with intID as an auto-numbered primary key. There were some gaps in the autonumbering as some records were deleted. I converted the table into a Sharepoint list. Somehow the new intID column re-numbered all records and eliminated the gaps and stored the original values in a new column, _OldID. Now my relationships are messed up because the intIDs other tables refer to are owned by different records. The Sharepoint intID column is read-only and I cannot edit the column properties either.
I thought about making the _OldID the new primary key, but I can't make it auto-number. I tried to edit the new intID values but cannot. I tried to eliminate the gaps in the original records and re-convert to Sharepoint but I can't edit those either. Any guidance would be appreciated.

To better help you solve your problem, it is recommended that you describe your problem in more detail.
